# Spring Framework migrating project to anotation configuration JAVA

Tags: java, spring

I want to rewrite a project using anotation configuration. But i have a problem with setting up a requst mapping. I will copy one of the controllers and hope that someone will help me with the url. `localhost:8080/projectName/{url}`

```
@Controller

   public class HomeController {

        private String homeView;

        private DomainManager domainManager;

        public void setHomeView(String homeView) {
            this.homeView = homeView;
        }

        public void setDomainManager(DomainManager domainManager) {
            this.domainManager = domainManager;
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String showPage(HttpSession session, Model model) {
            User u = (User) session.getAttribute(User.SESSION_PROPERTY);

            Domain domain = domainManager.getDomain(u.getDomainId());
            Quota used = domainManager.getQuotaUsage(u.getDomainId());
            boolean active = domainManager.isDomainActive(u.getDomainId());

            model.addAttribute("domain", domain);
            model.addAttribute("active", active);
            model.addAttribute("used", used);

            return homeView;
        }

    }
```

Comment: @RequestMapping((value = "/url",method = RequestMethod.GET) , Can you try this ? adding url mapping value

Comment: Annoatate `HomeController` With `@Controller`

Comment: @Backtrack I know that i can add url using using request mapping. I am trying to configure which is the url now because this controller is from a working prokect.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add annotation @Controller on your class, look the spring doc http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: I copied the controller without the annotation. It is edited.

Comment: you need to specify url like @Backtrack said

Comment: is there some other way to set a url because this controller is from a production code. (From a currently working projcet).